# If Statement Syntax

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

In this script the variable bankid evaluates to B1 but I cannot make this a condition but get an "if statement not defined"

```
    function BankTemplate() {
    //copy  all Bs!;
    var 
    bp=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Bs").activate();
    var bankid = bp.getSheetValues(3, 6, 1, 1); 
    If(bankid == "B1")
    {
      var 

 bp=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Bs").activate();
      var arraytocopy =  bp.getSheetValues(1, 1, 60, 20);
      var arrayNew  =  bp.getRange(65, 1, 60, 20).setValues(arraytocopy);
    }
```

Comment: You can't use a capital letter "I" in the word "if".   Change to lower case "i"

Comment: Review your JavaScript language reference of choice when resolving `SyntaxError`s

Comment: Oh so simple.  Thanks.